# Get Elasticsearch result from a NEST C# nested aggregation

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have this Elasticsearch NEST query:

```
var res = elastic.Search<SegmentRecord>(s => s.Index(esIndex).Aggregations(a => a.Terms("agg", x => x.Field(o => o.InstrumentName).Aggregations(a1 => a1.Terms("agg2", f => f.Field(y => y.GroupId))))));
```

how can I cycle through all the `InstrumentName` fields, and for each of those, cycle through all the `GroupId` fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Nest 5.4.0

```
foreach (var bucket in res.Aggs.Terms("agg").Buckets)
         {
             foreach (var innerBucket in bucket.Terms("agg2").Buckets)
             {
                 System.Console.WriteLine($"agg:{bucket.Key}, agg2:{innerBucket.Key} - {innerBucket.DocCount}");
             }
         }
```

Comment: doc link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html#aggs-vs-aggregations

Comment: have hit this a while ago and [found a great article on the matter](https://rimdev.io/working-with-nested-aggregates-using-nest-and-elasticsearch/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I accessed my children buckets with nested aggregations.

```
var yourAgg = result.Aggregations.Terms("YourParentField");
foreach (var child in yourAgg .Buckets)
{
   var aggs = child.Terms("YourChildField").Buckets;
   foreach (var item in aggs)
   {
      perDealerAggItems.Add(new AggregateItem()
        {
              Count = item.DocCount ?? 0,
              Key = item.Key,
              ParentList = field
          });
     }
}
```